# Android: using Spannable for putting text with bullets into TextView

Tags: android, textview, spannablestring

I need to put some text in a several languages.
The text looks like:

**Title**

- one
- two
- three

**Anouther Title**

- one
- two
- three

Bullets have different colour than anouther text.

I heared about `Spannable` in `Android`, but unfortunaly I can use `span` only with `from` and `end` int values. The problem in that that in different languages my words will have different positions, and so spannable text is not for me. Could you help me to solve this in easy way.

Comment: Are your texts in your res file?

Comment: @Androider, for different translations String has different chars positions, so it's not solution for me.

Comment: I recently wrote a small wrapper method for something similar, which I think might be helpful for you to start. Please check that it and get back. What it does, it mainly colors a certain part of your text to a diferent color and I think you could use the logic from there to adapt it to your own needs. http://stackoverflow.com/a/33246872/2642390

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got so sick of dealing with bulleted text that I wrote a `TextView` subclass I call `BulletTextView`.

I have texts in the resource file, as you do.  I formatted all the texts to use the Unicode bullet character \u2022 to mark the bullets.  So a sample text might look like this:

```
<string name="product_description_text">Our product is absolutely amazing, because 
    it has these features:
    \n\n\u2022 First awesome feature
    \n\u2022 Second awesome feature
    \n\u2022 Third awesome feature
    \n\n(Note that users with a free trial license can\'t access these features.)\n</string>
```

`BulletTextView` overrides `TextView.setText()` to scan the text for the bullet characters, remove them and save the positions to mark the bulleted spans:

```
@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    List<Integer> markers = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length(); i++) {
        char ch = text.charAt(i);

        switch (ch) {

        case '\u2022':

            // we found a bullet, mark the start of bullet span but don't append the bullet char
            markers.add(sb.length());

            // ... I do some other stuff here to skip whitespace etc.
            break;

        case '\n':

            // we found a newline char, mark the end of the bullet span
            sb.append(ch);
            markers.add(sb.length());

            // ... I do some stuff here to weed out the newlines without matching bullets

            break;

        // ... I have some special treatment for some other characters,
        //     for instance, a tab \t means a newline within the span

        default:
            // any other character just add it to the string
            sb.append(ch);
            break;
        }
    }

    // ... at the end of the loop I have some code to check for an unclosed span

    //  create the spannable to put in the TextView
    SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(sb.toString());

    // go through the markers two at a time and set the spans
    for (int i = 0; i < markers.size(); i += 2) {
        int start = markers.get(i);
        int end = markers.get(i+1);
        spannableString.setSpan(new BulletSpan(gapWidth), start, end, Spannable.SPAN_PARAGRAPH);
    }

    super.setText(spannableString, BufferType.SPANNABLE);
}
```

I left out some code that was specific to my application, but this is the basic framework for solving your problem.

Not sure about making your bullet a different color, but there is a `BulletSpan` constructor `public BulletSpan(int gapWidth, int color)` that may do the trick.

I tried to figure out how to use LineHeight to make larger lines to separate the bullet paragraphs, but I couldn't make it work.  I just use a newline to separate the two bullet sections.

Answer (score 2):

Native Android `TextView` doesn't support HTML `ul`/`li` elements (bullet lists). So, two (or more) options you would have:

- Using [workarounds](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5891755/1841194) with native `TextView`.
- Using 3rd party libraries. For example [html-textview](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview) fits your requirement.

  [Examples of html-textview](https://github.com/SufficientlySecure/html-textview#example).