# Change Android TextView bullet color

Tags: android, xml, textview

I am using bullet in a TextView in XML code and I don't know why its color is red in some devices while my TextView color is white. It can be because of device default theme. How can I make it white.

Activity theme:

```
 <style name="AppThemeOnBoarding" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
</style>
```

My XML code:

```
<TextView
   android:gravity="center"
   android:padding="20dp"
   style="@style/TextView_shadow"
   android:layout_centerInParent="true"
   android:alpha="0.9"
   android:textSize="13sp"
   android:textColor="#ffffff"
   android:text="i Verbindung am besten mit: \n✔ ABC\n✔ XYZ"
   android:id="@+id/fitbit_connectiondesc"
   android:layout_below="@id/fitbit_label"
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

[image: Result]

Comment: Hallo, did you try with - setText("\u2714 Bullet"); - lg

Comment: No I am gonna try

Comment: Not working I think issue is with the device default theme.

Comment: maybe your answer is here http://stackoverflow.com/a/33509165/5281666

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found an alternate method to achieve this. I am using `Spannable` to set "bullet tick" Image in between TextView, an alternate for bullet.
This is working perfectly.

```
String string = "i Verbindung am besten mit: \n ABC \n XYZ";
String abc = "ABC";
String xyz = "XYZ";

SpannableString spannableString = new SpannableString(string);

int startPosition1 = string.indexOf(abc);
int startPosition2 = string.indexOf(xyz);
    
Bitmap bullettick = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.tick_bullet);
    
spannableString.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context,bullettick ), startPosition1-2, startPosition1, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
spannableString.setSpan(new ImageSpan(context, bullettick ), startPosition2-2, startPosition2, Spannable.SPAN_INCLUSIVE_INCLUSIVE );
textview.setText(spannableString);
textview.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Answer (score 1):

[image: check this image]

```
 tv.setText(Html.fromHtml("i Verbindung am besten mit:" + "<font color=\"#ffffff\">" +"<br>✔ ABC <br>✔ XYZ"+ "</font><br><br>"));
```

//xml like

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

use this programmatically to set the white color

```
mTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
```

Answer (score 0):

Refer `TextView` in your `Activity` and set text in `html` format as in

```
TextView fitbitTV = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fitbit_connectiondesc);
String content = "<font color='#FFFFFF'>i Verbindung am besten mit: \n✔ ABC\n✔ XYZ</font>";
fitbitTV.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
```

Answer (score 0):

Create html string with font as below.

```
 Html.fromHtml("<![CDATA[<font color='#145A14'>text</font>]]>");
```

this is sample code.

or

Use  'android:textColor'
in text  style.

Answer (score 0):

use this in style

```
<item name="android:textColor">@color/AppThemeOnBoarding</item>

<style name="AppThemeOnBoarding" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar.FullScreen">
 <item name="android:textColor">@color/AppThemeOnBoarding</item>
</style>
```