# Show only 1st item and hide same name items in recyclerView in Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview

I would like to show only 1st position item and hide other same text items in recyclerView. just like image below.

[image]

I know I can hide the view with `holder.itemView.visibility = View.GONE`, but what condition should I implement to achieve this? Thank you.

Comment: Please share code of your recyclerview adapter so that I can provide you with changed code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could resolve this problem with
[How do I display the calendar date on the top of chat messages?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33226491/how-do-i-display-the-calendar-date-on-the-top-of-chat-messages)

Get previous position with

```
if(position > 0) {
            val previousPosition = cellList[position -1]
        }
```

and compare with current position.
Thanks for you guys' help!

Answer (score 2):

I have a counter idea. I feel the list should be filtered for uniqueness before displaying in the recyclerview.

Having something like:

```
data class Fruits(val name: String, val timeStamp :String)
val fruits = listOf(
    Fruits("Apples", "Foo"),
    Fruits("Apples", "Bar"),
    Fruits("Oranges", "Foo"),
    Fruits("Apples", "Bar")
)
```

then using:

```
fruits.distinctBy{
    it.name
}
```

should remove duplicate items with the same name and this is what you pass to the adapter

Answer (score 0):

I want to complete answer of my friend Robin
if u want to hold the first item, you should also sort them

```
fruits.sortedByDescending { it.date }.distinctBy { it.name }
```